# Missing entries from csv source file

Tags: python, csv

I have a dataset with 715,014 entries. This is a work confidential file so I cannot upload the csv file. Here's the first 10 rows:

IP,Ping,Hostname,Ports

172.20.1.1,4 ms,[n/a],[n/s]

172.20.1.2,3 ms,[n/a],[n/s]

172.20.1.3,3 ms,[n/a],[n/s]

172.20.1.4,[n/a],[n/s],[n/s]

172.20.1.5,[n/a],[n/s],[n/s]

172.20.1.6,[n/a],[n/s],[n/s]

172.20.1.7,[n/a],[n/s],[n/s]

172.20.1.8,[n/a],[n/s],[n/s]

172.20.1.9,0 ms,[n/a],[n/s]
172.20.1.10,1 ms,d36b3yz1-phth.regis.net,[n/s]

Here's what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
df = pd.read_csv('Userpc.csv',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, error_bad_lines=False)
df.info()
```

**Result:**

RangeIndex: 1448 entries, 0 to 1447

Data columns (total 4 columns):

IP          1448 non-null object

Ping        1448 non-null object

Hostname    1448 non-null object

Ports       1447 non-null object

dtypes: object(4)

memory usage: 45.3+ KB

How can Pandas missed most of my data? When I write into a new .csv file, it also contain only 1448 rows instead of the full 700,000 rows.

Thank you for your time, and sorry for any bad formatting in my question!

Comment: Find a small subset of your data that shows the problem.

Comment: When there is something other than [n/s] in a record for Ports what would it be?

Comment: @BillBell Ports are all [n/s].

Answer (score 0):

Rather than guessing what it is that Pandas finds unacceptable, vet the input carefully first. Read each line of input, parse it, replace items likely to be troublesome for Pandas, and store them temporarily. When you find a line that cannot be parsed successfully print it for inspection, and then alter the parser to accommodate the new case that you have identified.

Some examples:

- Enclose IP addresses and hostnames in double quotation marks; ie, "172.20.1.1" and "d36b3yz1-phth.regis.net".
- Replace ping times given in msec such as '4 ms' with just the number, in this case, 4. If you find later that some ping times are in the minutes range then adjust your parser.
- Replace ping times of [n/a] with the empty string.
- Replace Ports of [n/s] with the empty string unless there is data there in which case enclose the data in double quotation marks.
- Try to split each line on the blank character so that, when you encounter a line like the tenth in your sample you will be able to detect the presence of two records, each to be handled separately as detailed above.

I would say, put the temporary records in a (temporary) sqlite3 database table which is easily dropped into Pandas.